# Set order of viewmodel creation in catel

Tags: catel

Is it possible to set a order in which the viewmodels are created.
I want to display logmessages in a own view. Some other views are created before, and their logs on startup ar not displayed because they are created befor this logview.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, since they are loaded on-demand when the views are loaded (and that's up to WPF).

There are a few options:

1. [Recommended] Create a service that holds the log messages from the start. Then the log vm loads the service and retrieves the messages it missed. Then the service (which you have full control over) will keep track of the log, and you can even hide the log view in between and still show all messages.
2. Create a custom implementation of the IViewModelFactory. Then you have full control of when and how vm's are created. Then you can create a LogViewModel at the beginning of the factory and return it once it is required by Catel.

Comment: Then thats only one more service just to hold all messages. Why does the log listener not hold all logs?

Comment: Depends on the log listener your are using. There is a MemoryLogListener, it will hold it. But who will own it?

Comment: You mean the RollingInMemoryLogListener? (Why RollingIn??) 
Who will own it. Who will own the additional Service. The ServiceLocator I would think.

Comment: RollingInMemoryLogListener because we don't want to spam the memory. You can always create your own non-rolling in memory log listener. The additional service will live inside the ServiceLocator, that's correct, but then the service will be available to anything. You can also register your log listener in the service locator if you want (but I find that more confusing than a service).